# Rememer page of pagination

Tags: jquery

I have code below which works very conveniently, but I don't know how to add code in pagination so that the code remembers the actual page when the page is refreshed.

```
$('.table-wrap').after('<div class="pagination-wrap"></div>');
$('.pagination-wrap').append('<div class="pagination"></div>');
$('.pagination').append('<ul class="pagination__list"></ul>');
var rowsShown = 10;
var rowsTotal = $('.table tbody tr').length;
var numPages = rowsTotal/rowsShown;
for(i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
    var pageNum = i + 1;
    $('.pagination__list').append('<li class="pagination__item" rel="'+i+'"><a class="pagination__link href="#" >'+pageNum+'</a></li>');
}
$('.table tbody tr').hide();
$('.table tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
$('.pagination-wrap li:first').addClass('is-current');
$('.pagination-wrap li').bind('click', function(){

    $('.pagination-wrap li').removeClass('is-current');
    $(this).addClass('is-current');
    var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
    var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
    var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
    $('.table tbody tr').css('opacity','0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
    css('display','table-row').animate({opacity:1}, 300);
});
```

Comment: Either keep it in a session or In a LocalStorage.

Comment: I know how to use LocalStorage to keep value in input but I don't know how use it in paganation